# Mysql case with or condition with or operator

Tags: mysql

How we select record in given mysql query :
kindly help me to select query with case when var1 like value1 or var2 like value2 then 'valid' else 'invalid' from xx as s

```
select
    case
        when SUBSTRING(Trim(Pan_No), 4, 1) ='C'
        and (z.tds_Vendor_Type_Lookup_Code not like '%COMP%' or Vendor_Name not like '%Pvt%' or Vendor_Name not like '%Ldt%' or Vendor_Name not like '%Limited%' or Vendor_Name not like '%Private%'  )
    then 'InValid Pan 4th Character for a Company' end as code
    from xyz as a
```

---

in this query always run else condition please guide me a valid way.

Comment: and please give me suggestion that how we debug mysql procedure in linux pc

Comment: you're missing end of case statement

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `end` statement for the case, in addition you can also add `else` something as

```
select 
case
 when SUBSTRING(Trim(Pan_No), 4, 1) ='C' 
 and (
   z.tds_Vendor_Type_Lookup_Code not like '%COMP%' 
   or Vendor_Name not like '%Pvt%' 
   or Vendor_Name not like '%Ldt%' 
   or Vendor_Name not like '%Limited%' 
   or Vendor_Name not like '%Private%'  
 ) 
 then 'InValid Pan 4th Character for a Company' 
 else 'Valid' end as validity
 from xyz
```

Comment: actually this query is a only part of sub query in this case always run else condition i want solution  in the given query full query is: